# AngularJS: Accessing json data stored in jQuery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, cookies

Using AngularJS, i understand how to fetch JSON data using an AJAX request. This is done as follows:

```
    $http.get('data/parks.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.parks = data;
    });
```

However, I am currently storing JSON information within a jQuery Cookie as oppose to in a document on the server, which I need to access using an AJAX request.

The data is stored in the cookie using the following code:

```
// Add the selected park to the users favourite list
$scope.addFavourite=function(id){

    // If user has cookie named userFavourites
    if(typeof $.cookie("userFavourites") != "undefined"){

        // Turn the cookie data into readable JSON
        var favourites = $.parseJSON($.cookie("userFavourites"));

        // Filter through the the results of the JSON object and check to see if the result is equal to the selected parks ID
        var repeated = favourites.filter(function(a){
            return a.id == id
        }).length;

        // If park is not in the list, add it to the list
        if(!repeated){
            favourites.push({"id":id});
            if($.cookie("userFavourites", JSON.stringify(favourites))){
                alertify.success("Successfully added park to favourites");
            }
            else alertify.eror("Failed to store park in cookie");
        }

        // Inform the user that the park is already a favourite
        else alertify.error("Oops... This park is already in your favourites list!");

    }
    else{
        var favourites = [{ "id":id }];        
        $.cookie("userFavourites", JSON.stringify(favourites));
        alertify.success("Successfully added park to favourites");
    } 
}
```

The information adds to the cookie just fine and once I have added some parks into the cookie, when i console.log it I get:

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2}]
```

My problem is when I want to fetch the data using AJAX within AngularJS, I'm not sure how to get JSON data from a cookie as oppose to from a file within the folder structures.

I have tried the following but it only returns an error in the console:

```
$scope.listFavourites=function(){

    if(typeof $.cookie("userFavourites") != "undefined"){

        $http.get($.cookie("userFavourites")).success(function(data){

            $scope.favourites = data;
            $scope.totalFavourites = data.length;

        });

    }
    else{
        $scope.favourites = "Empty";
    }

    console.log($scope.favourites);

}
```

Error:

```
GET http://www.example.com/angularjs/[%7B%22id%22:1%7D,%7B%22id%22:2%7D] 404 (Not Found)
```

I have also tried to change the $http.get to $http.jsonp following this documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) but I haven't had any luck with it.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: the cookie and its content are stored on the local machine, GET, POST or success( makes no sense here; `$.cookie("userFavourites")` is all you should need/care about

Answer (score 1):

Cookie is a local element in the browser and not on the server, so you do not fetch it using ajax, instead you can simply print its value in javascript

```
console.log($cookies.get('myFavoriteCookie'));
```

more details [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

Comment: Of course it is, why didn't I think of that. Classic case of mind block at the minute! Thank for the input. I'd upvote your answer but don't have enough points :/